# Evaluating $\int^1_0 x^n \sqrt{1+x} dx$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: integration

As in the title, my question is very simple: how can I evaluate:

$$ I_n = \int_0^1 x^n \sqrt{1+x} \;dx $$

where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Seeing as n is a natural, I feel like one way I could approach this question is through induction, but I would need to know the answer first to prove it is correct, so I don't think that's how I am supposed to do this.

The other thing I tried was to integrate by parts to get a relationship between $I_n$ and $I_{n-1}$, then solve it to get a closed form for $I_n$. When I try that, for example if we let $u = x^n$ and $dv/dx = \sqrt{1+x}$

$$
I_n = \left[ 2/3 \;x^n(x+1)^{3/2}\right]^1_0 - 2n/3\int^1_0\;x^{n-1}(x+1)^{3/2}\;dx
$$

But there seems to be no point in going further, since I can't see how to make the right hand side into an expression involving $\int x^{n-1}\sqrt{x+1}$.

Is there something I missed? This problem is allegedly not that difficult, so I would appreciate some help.

Comment: One option: $x^n\sqrt{1+x}=(u-1)^n\sqrt{u}=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}u^{k+1/2}$ $\to\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\frac{u^{k+3/2}}{k+3/2}+C=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\frac{(x+1)^{k+3/2}}{k+3/2}+C$. Not clear if there is a good way to simplify the final summation.

Comment: You are close to something useful. Note that $x^{n-1}(x+1)^{3/2}=x^n(x+1)^{1/2}+x^{n-1}(x+1)^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering $$I_n = \int x^n \sqrt{1+x} \;dx$$ may be, we could change variable $$x=\sinh^2(t)\implies dx=2 \sinh (t) \cosh (t)$$ This makes $$I_n=2\int \cosh ^2(t) \sinh ^{2 n+1}(t)\;dt=2\int \sinh^{2n+1}(t)\;dt+2\int \sinh^{2n+3}(t)\;dt$$ Now, we can use [the reduction formulae](http://homepages.lboro.ac.uk/~maak2/intechpdf/trig/shchevenprf.pdf)$$\int \sinh^m(t)\;dt=\frac 1m \cosh(t) \sinh^{m-1}(t)-\frac {m-1}m \int\sinh^{m-2}(t)\;dt$$

Answer (score 1):

Reduction Formula
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_n & =\int x^n \sqrt{1+x}\, d x \\
& =\int \frac{x^n+x^{n+1}}{\sqrt{1+x}} d x \\
& =2 \int\left(x^n+x^{n+1}\right) d(\sqrt{1+x}) \\
& =2\left(x^n+x^{n+1}\right) \sqrt{1+x}-2 n \int x^{n-1} \sqrt{1+x}\, d x -2 (n+1) \int x^{n} \sqrt{1+x}\, d x \\
& =2\left(x^n+x^{n+1}\right) \sqrt{1+x}-2 n I_{n-1}-2(n+1) I_n \\
I_n & =\frac{2\left(x^n+x^{n+1}\right) \sqrt{1+x}}{2 n+3}-\frac{2 n}{2 n+3} I_{n-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

An explicit formula may be obtained as using the [definition](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19.E3) and [series expansion](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19.E11) of the generalised exponential integral $E_p(z)$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
&\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{I_n }}{{n!}}z^n }  = \int_0^1 {{\rm e}^{ - zx} \sqrt {1 + x} \,{\rm d}x}  = {\rm e}^z \int_1^2 {{\rm e}^{ - zt} t^{1/2} {\rm d}t} \\ & = {\rm e}^z E_{ - 1/2} (z) - 2\sqrt 2 {\rm e}^z E_{ - 1/2} (2z)
\\ & = \frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{2}{\rm e}^{ - z} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{2^{n + 3/2} n!}}{{\Gamma (n + 5/2)}}\frac{{z^n }}{{n!}}}  - \frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{n!}}{{\Gamma (n + 5/2)}}\frac{{z^n }}{{n!}}} 
\\ & = \frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {( - 1)^{n - k} \binom{n}{k}\frac{{2^{k + 3/2} k!}}{{\Gamma (k + 5/2)}}} } \right)\frac{{z^n }}{{n!}}}  - \frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{n!}}{{\Gamma (n + 5/2)}}\frac{{z^n }}{{n!}}} 
\\ & = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{2}\left( {( - 1)^{n + 1} \frac{{n!}}{{\Gamma (n + 5/2)}} + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {( - 1)^k \binom{n}{k}\frac{{2^{k + 3/2} k!}}{{\Gamma (k + 5/2)}}} } \right)\frac{{z^n }}{{n!}}} 
\\ & = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \left( {( - 1)^{n + 1} \frac{{2^{2n + 2} n!(n + 1)!}}{{(2n + 3)!}} + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {( - 1)^k \binom{n}{k}\frac{{2^{3k + 7/2} k!(k + 1)!}}{{(2k + 3)!}}} } \right)\frac{{z^n }}{{n!}}} .
\end{align*}
Thus,
$$
I_n  = ( - 1)^{n + 1} \frac{{2^{2n + 2} n!(n + 1)!}}{{(2n + 3)!}} + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {( - 1)^k \binom{n}{k}\frac{{2^{3k + 7/2} k!(k + 1)!}}{{(2k + 3)!}}} .
$$